# To create a loop or function for collecting values of multiple vectors calculated using other column values in a dataframe in another dataframe in r?

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe , a snapshot of which is given below giving country,var name (Conva,EMP), year in first3 and values for variables  AGR, MFR and SER  in the next 3 columns.  I would like to calculate log of ConVA/EMP based on variables in var name column and values in AGR:SER cols for each year by each country. the example dataframe df is given below

df

Country Var Year    AGR MFR SER

CHN    ConVA 1952   346 921  108

CHN    ConVA 1953   342 143  432

CHN    EMP   1952   171 432  313

CHN    EMP   1953   199 300  432

HKG   ConVA  2001   905 118  106

HKG   EMP   2001    604 254  320

I do this by the following code for  AGR:
`dfagrloglabpr<-select( df, Country, Variable, Year, AGR) %>% spread(Variable, AGR) %>% mutate(AGRLabProd = ConVA/EMP) %>% mutate( LogAGRLabProd= log(AGRLabProd))%>% select(Country, year, LogAGRLabProd))`     which gives me log values for AGR as desired.  But if i want to have  the log values for all of the sectors (AGR,MFR,SER) in one dataframe by country and year by creating a loop or a function, i run into problems.  I have tried using loops by sector but it gives me a error everytime. Any solutions or tips for a code which will run it by sector and collect values in a dataframe?   Otherwise i can only think of running the code individually for each sector and then merging but that becomes cumbersome as the number of sectors increase.

Comment: Have just  added a table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to apply for multiple columns, use `mutate_at`, after grouping by 'Country', 'Year' (assuming that there are 1 row each for 'ConVA', 'EMP', subset the columns selected in `mutate_at` and divide by the corresponding value where the string is 'EMP' and take the `log`

```
library(dplyr)   
df1 %>%
     group_by(Country, Year) %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(AGR:SER),  list(LogLabProd = ~ 
                   log(.[Var == 'ConVA']/.[Var == 'EMP'])))
# A tibble: 6 x 9
# Groups:   Country, Year [3]
#  Country Var    Year   AGR   MFR   SER AGR_LogLabProd MFR_LogLabProd SER_LogLabProd
#  <chr>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#1 CHN     ConVA  1952   346   921   108          0.705          0.757          -1.06
#2 CHN     ConVA  1953   342   143   432          0.542         -0.741           0   
#3 CHN     EMP    1952   171   432   313          0.705          0.757          -1.06
#4 CHN     EMP    1953   199   300   432          0.542         -0.741           0   
#5 HKG     ConVA  2001   905   118   106          0.404         -0.767          -1.10
#6 HKG     EMP    2001   604   254   320          0.404         -0.767          -1.10
```

which is the same output in `summarise`d form using `OP's code

```
select( df1, Country, Var, Year, AGR) %>% 
     spread(Var, AGR) %>% 
     mutate(AGRLabProd = ConVA/EMP) %>% 
     mutate( LogAGRLabProd= log(AGRLabProd))%>% 
     select(Country, Year, LogAGRLabProd)
#   Country Year LogAGRLabProd
#1     CHN 1952     0.7047752
#2     CHN 1953     0.5415059
#3     HKG 2001     0.4043607
```

---

If we. don't need to create new columns, but only `summarise`d output, then use `summarise_at` instead of `mutate_at`

```
df1 %>%
     group_by(Country, Year) %>% 
     summarise_at(vars(AGR:SER),  list(LogLabProd = ~ 
                   log(.[Var == 'ConVA']/.[Var == 'EMP'])))
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   Country [2]
#  Country  Year AGR_LogLabProd MFR_LogLabProd SER_LogLabProd
#  <chr>   <int>          <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#1 CHN      1952          0.705          0.757          -1.06
#2 CHN      1953          0.542         -0.741           0   
#3 HKG      2001          0.404         -0.767          -1.10
```

By doing this, we are effectively skipping the reshaping part

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Country = c("CHN", "CHN", "CHN", "CHN", "HKG", 
"HKG"), Var = c("ConVA", "ConVA", "EMP", "EMP", "ConVA", "EMP"
), Year = c(1952L, 1953L, 1952L, 1953L, 2001L, 2001L), AGR = c(346L, 
342L, 171L, 199L, 905L, 604L), MFR = c(921L, 143L, 432L, 300L, 
118L, 254L), SER = c(108L, 432L, 313L, 432L, 106L, 320L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: It gives me the following error : Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character".

Comment: @user12081247. Are you using the same `data` in my post.  Also, what is the package version for `dplyr`.  I used `packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.8.3’`

Comment: Yeah its the same dplyr version. The original dataframe is like this:str(df)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 1629 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ Country : chr  "CHN" "CHN" "CHN" "CHN" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Country"
  ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%9s"
 $ Variable: chr  "ConVA" "ConVA" "ConVA" "ConVA" ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Variable"
  ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%9s"
 $ Year    : num  1952 1953 1954 1955 1956 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Year"
 $ AGR     : num  3.46e+11 3.52e+11 3.58e+11 3.89e+11 4.08e+11 ...

Comment: @user12081247.You haven't replied whether the error is from testing this data or the original data.  If it i from original data, pleaes use `dput` to copy paste that output  (`dput(head(yourdata, 10))` in your post to understand the structure

Comment: I reloaded the dplyr package and now the group_by error is not there. Instead the error is Error: Column AGR_LogLabProd must be length 1 (the group size), not 0. Coyuld this be because length of ConVA and EMP vectors by years for some countries  differs in some cases in the dataset?

Comment: Ok , after matching the Con_VA and Emp vectors for the same number of years , the solution works. Thanks so much , all the solutions offered are elegant and informative. Just one small query - is there a way to ensure the length of vectors by year for ConVA and employment for each country matches and the non matches are dropped ?

Comment: @user12081247  Hi, you can use a `filter` after the `group_by` step `filter(n_distinct(Var) == 2) %>%`

Comment: Thanks  so much ! that works , but can you just explain what filter(n_distinct(Var)==2) exactly does over here? I am a bit  vague about it  being relatiely new to R

Comment: @user12081247  It checks whether the number of distinct elements in 'Var' column is 2 or not